# How can I count just the active rows and not the soft deletes

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have my 3 tables and I want to count all the active serial assets.

I need to display the Serialised Inventory rows but the details might not have been added to the SerialAssets table so this gives me NULL rows.
This works fine like this...

```
SELECT inv.Id AS Id, COUNT(s.Id) AS Total, MIN(i.Name) AS Asset
FROM SerialAssets AS s
RIGHT JOIN Inventories AS inv ON s.InventoryId = inv.Id
INNER JOIN Items AS i ON inv.ItemId = i.Id
WHERE i.Serialised = 1
GROUP BY inv.Id
```

But now I have added soft delete I need to only count the active SerialAssets, so adding AND s.Active = 1 to the WHERE works but it removes the null valued rows that normally get displayed as 0. Its obviously because if s.Active is null its not selected, so is there a way to change the count or make s.active = 1 or null?

**UPDATE**

Solved by:

**Damien_The_Unbeliever**
&
**Lieven**

Thanks for the quick replies!

Comment: So you don't actually want a count, you want to filter your select statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `AND s.Active = 1` into the *join* conditions, rather than into the where clause:

```
SELECT inv.Id AS Id, COUNT(s.Id) AS Total, MIN(i.Name) AS Asset
FROM SerialAssets AS s
RIGHT JOIN Inventories AS inv ON s.InventoryId = inv.Id
         AND s.Active = 1
INNER JOIN Items AS i ON inv.ItemId = i.Id
WHERE i.Serialised = 1
GROUP BY inv.Id
```

By the time that the `WHERE` clause is (logically) assessed, it doesn't care what the origin of each column in the result set was - all it cares about is assessing the conditions against the values in those columns. If those columns contain `NULL`s, it doesn't know whether that's because that column contained `NULL` in the base table, or it was the result of an unsuccessful outer `JOIN`.

Comment: Haha, that was simple! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If active is always 1, 0, or null, you can just `SUM` active.

A more general solution would look like this

```
SUM(CASE
        WHEN /*insert active condition here*/ THEN 1
        ELSE 0
    END) AS ActiveCount
```

Comment: Ok... but not sure how that helps me, could I have some more information please

Answer (score 1):

Change the `s.Active= 1` to either

- `ISNULL(s.Active, 1) = 1`
- `COALESCE(s.Active, 1) = 1`

[ISNULL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933210%28v=sql.80%29.aspx)

> Replaces NULL with the specified replacement value.

[COALESCE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258244%28v=sql.80%29.aspx)

> Returns the first nonnull expression among its arguments.

Answer (score 0):

I might not get the problem... but are you trying to count all s.Id that are equal to 1 without filtering the rows the query returns?

If that is the case:

Replace `count(s.Id)` with `count(case when s.Id = 1 then 1 end)`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    SELECT inv.Id AS Id, 
            SUM(CASE WHEN COALESCE(s.ACtive, 1) = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Total, 
            MIN(i.Name) AS Asset
    FROM Inventories AS inv
            INNER JOIN Items AS i ON inv.ItemId = i.Id
            LEFT OUTER JOIN SerialAssets AS s ON 
                    inv.Id = s.InventoryId
    WHERE i.Serialised = 1
    GROUP BY inv.Id
```

I have rearranged your query. It's better to use LEFT OUTER JOINs instead. It is a easier for humans to understand and SQL Server performs faster with the LEFT JOIN .